# How to Type a Word Into an Input, and Then Have Python Search for a Variable Named That in a Module?

Tags: python, dictionary, module, function

Sorry about the long title but I can't think of a better way to word this. I'm creating a basic sort of A.I. program, and one thing I want it to do is be able to define words, like a dictionary. Now I would use a python dictionary, but I want the database to stay intact after the program is finished, hence the reason I'm using a module. I also want the program to add to the module if the word isn't already defined.

Here's the part of the program I was using, but I'm stuck at this point:

```
from nouns import *
def search():
    try:
        print(nouns.(eval(definer)))
        #This gives me a syntax error
    except NameError:
        define = input("I do not know what this is. Define it for me please: ")
        n = open("nouns.py","a")
        n.write("\n")
        n.write(definer)
        n.write("=")
        n.write("\"")
        n.write(define)
        n.write("\"")
        n.close()
        print("You will have to restart the program before it recognizes the new   definition.")
    asking()

def asking():
    global words
    thewords = input("What do you want to talk about next?\n")
    words = thewords.lower()
    main()

def main():
    global definer

    defining = ("what is a ")
    if defining in words and ("?") in words:
        definerr = str(words[10:-1])
        definer = definerr.lower()
        search()

    defining = ("what is ")
    if defining in words and ("?") in words:
        definerr = str(words[8:-1])
        definer = definerr.lower()
        search()

    defining = ("what is a ")
    if defining in words:
        definerr = str(words[10:])
        definer = definerr.lower()
        search()

    defining = ("what is ")
    if defining in words:
        definerr = str(words[8:])
        definer = definerr.lower()
        search()

asking()
```

So, how do I type a word into an input, then have python search for a word named that variable, and finally have python print that variable in the original program?

Comment: new values added to a module won't persist into new instantiations of the program. You should use a regular dict, and load/save it to a file using `pickle` or `json` or similar.

Comment: I really think you should use a `dict`. You can use the `json` package to import it from a file (serializes to JSON) and edit it in-memory. When the program finishes just save it to your file and you're done.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I'm not that familiar with the json module or javascript, and the coding looks to be a bit beyond my understanding. Is there any way I can get a bit of a simpler explanation than the python doc on it gives?

Comment: @1adog1 added an example to get you started

Comment: Thanks! I'm just changing the program to make sure it works and I at least kind of understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Got the program working! I would mark upvote both answers, but my reputation's too low. Thanks Chris and Reut!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code to get you started using the `json` module and in-memory `dict` editing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import os

FILE = "defs.json"

# load file (if exists...)
if not os.path.exists(FILE):
    defs = {}
else:
    with open(FILE) as defs_file:
        try:
            defs = json.load(defs_file)
        except ValueError:
            # invalid file - replace it with valid empty file
            defs = {}

# do stuff...    
defs['new definition'] = 'new value'

# save dict to the file
with open(FILE, 'w') as defs_file:
    json.dump(defs, defs_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to store your objects in file or something similar. If you want you dictionary to be editable from outside the application I'd recommend [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), if you want it to only be editable from with your application, use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html). I'll give a json example:

words.json:

```
{
    'thing': 'some object'
}
```

python:

```
import json
with open('words.json') as f:
    words = json.load(f)

print words['thing']
... # Your program here, then as a final act before finishing

with open('words.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(words, f)
```